# jQuery change does not trigger when a dropdownlist holds one item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger events when options in a dropdown are clicked on. I couldn't find anything that explains how to do this. What I want is to fire the event and use the value of it. When i use **.on** instead of **.change** I fire the event everytime the select is clicked and thats not what I want because I only want to use the value of the selected item.

Assume this is dynamically generated:

```
<select id="dropdownOne">
<option value="1">NumberOne</option>
</select>
```

Assume this is dynamically generated:

```
<select id="dropdownTwo">
<option value="1">NumberOne</option>
<option value="2">NumberTwo</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("select").change("click", function () {
    //This event is not fired in dropdown one

    //This event is only fired in dropdown two if I change the option
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value == 1){
        console.log("This logs number 1");
    }else{
        console.log("This logs number 2");
    }
}
```

How can I:

- Trigger the event on an item in a dropdownlist that holds only one item
- Trigger the event on an item that is clicked multiple times

**EDIT:** So, my question was marked as a duplicate:

[How to call onchange event when dropdown values are same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850175/how-to-call-onchange-event-when-dropdown-values-are-same)

The "duplicate" has 6 answers:

Vicky Kumar: Says the code of that question is fine and working.
**This answer does not contribute to my problem**

ajpocus: Has an answer, got edited later saying that it doesn't work.
**Doesn't work**

Krupesh Kotecha: Uses a click event on the select, same behaviour as **.on** 
**This is not what I want**

Teja: Fixes the problem for that question but not mine, still doesn't trigger any event when te select only has 1 option or when you click an option more than once
**This is not what I want**

charu joshi: Uses **.on** event with :option selecter, doesn't work because the :option selecter is unknown, can also not be found in the jQuery API documentation
**Doesn't work**

derp: This answer explains how to remove duplicates and then uses the change event, this might work for the question of the "duplicate" but I never load in duplicate items in my select, and even then it still uses the change event which doesn't do what I want as explained in my question
**This answer does not contribute to my problem**

So all of the above answers from the "duplicate" question do not apply to my problem/question. Also none of those answers were marked as accepted by the original poster.

Comment: What is the concern with `change` event ? you can invoke the handler while registering event.. `$("select").on("change", function(){}).change();`

Comment: `$("select").change("click", function () {` or `$("select").on("click/change", function () {` ?

Comment: Having both `click` and `change` event on drop down is a bad idea, a change event is followed by a click itself on drop down. So better would be to decide when to attach the `click` event.

Comment: None of these work, eventually I want to trigger a change (or any) event that can handle a option click when there is only one option available in the dropdown, but I do not want to trigger the event yet by clicking the dropdown arrow,  only when the actual option is clicked.

Comment: try this `$( "select" )
  .change(function () { $('#select option:selected').val() }`

Comment: Nope, only works with at least 2 options in the select. Behaves like a regeular .change, nothing is happening when there is only 1 option.

Answer (score 4):

By definition:

> The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been
>   changed.

When there is only one option like:

```
<select id="dropdownOne">
   <option value="1">NumberOne</option>
</select>
```

No matter how many time you try to change/click the options, the value of select will remain same, **1**. And change event will never execute.

And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487274/3115653), `onSelect()` and `onClick()` events are not supported by the `<option>` tag.

I'd suggest you prepend an additional option with value -1 or 0 to your select.

```
<select id="dropdownOne">
    <option value="-1">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="1">NumberOne</option>
</select>
```

Or you can create a custom select control like suggested by [@Bradley Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37952328/3115653)

Comment: This is the most straightforward solution. The default selection of first option prevent onchange from firing. Adding a placeholder option to the top is the only way you can achieve this if you dont want to develop a custom dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var value;
$('select').focus(function () {
        value = this.value;
        if(value == 1){
            console.log("This logs number 1");
        }else{
            console.log("This logs number 2");
        }
    }).change(function() {
      value = this.value;
      if(value == 1){
        console.log("This logs number 1");
      }else{
        console.log("This logs number 2");
      }
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/cdantdor/

For the one item in the select drop down, I got the value focus event and after selecting item update the value by change event. Hopefully it will fulfill your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may satisfy your need although it isn't exactly what you asked for.  When you click on the button marked Options, it opens a little menu the vanishes when you click on Close Menu.  Although it isn't actually a pulldown menu, it acts as one.

The problem is that you are trying to alter the internals of a control rather than basing actions on the control itself.  Javascript has very little control over the internals of a control except as specified in the interface.

Look at http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         var button;
         var textarea;
         var menu;
         var closer;
         function starter() {
            button = document.getElementById("button");
            textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
            menu = document.getElementById("menu");
            closer = document.getElementById("close");
            textarea.value = "Display area for selections\r\n";
            button.onclick = open;
            closer.onclick = close;
         }
         function close() {
            menu.style.display = "none";
            menu.style.visibility = "hidden";
         }
         function open() {
            menu.style.display = "block";
            menu.style.visibility="visible";
         }
         function press(char) {
             textarea.value = textarea.value + char + "\r\n";
         }
         window.onload=starter;
      </script>
      <style>
         #menu { display:none; border: 2px solid black; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Click on button marked <i>Options</i> to open menu for selection.</p>
      <form>
         <div id="menu">
            <p>Clicking on options will cause them to appear in the text box</p>
            <ul>
               <li><input type="button" value="First" onclick="press('First');" /></li>
               <li><input type="button" value="Second" onclick="press('Second');" /></li>
               <li><input type="button" value="Third" onclick="press('Third');"</li>
               <li><input type="button" value="Close menu" id="close" /></li>
            </ul>
            <p>Click on <i>close menu</i> to close this section</p>
         </div>
         <p><input type="button" id="button" value="Options"  /> </p>
         <p><textarea cols="20" rows="20" id="textarea"></textarea></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```